# Генерация массивов

Tags: python

```
for i in range(20):
    i = [random.randint(0,1000)]
    print(i)
```

Нужно сделать 20 случайно сгенерированных массивов размером 10. В коде получилось так, что создаётся 20 массивов, но в них по 1 элементу. Как заполнить их 10, 100, 1000, 10000 рандомными элементами? Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: i = [random.randint(0,1000) for j in range(10)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроме генерации, списки же надо и сохранять:

```
import random
a = []
for i in range(5):
    a.append([random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(5)])
print(a)
```